# "Return" content when closing toggle

Tags: javascript

The goal is to hide the `#boxar` when the `toggle` is active and return the "#boxar" when "toggle is closed. The code works fine until I close the toggle (the "#boxar" disappears) but when I close the toggle, they won't return.

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle').click(function(){
        $('.boxar').hide();
        $('#'+this.rel+'').show();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **[`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** instead, like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle').click(function(){
        $('.boxar').toggle();
        $('#'+this.rel+'').toggle();

        return false;
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('.boxar').toggle();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).toggle();

    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type='button' id='toggle' rel='test'>Toggle</button>
<br>
<div class='boxar'>Boxar DIV</div>

<span>Regular span</span><br>
<span id="test">Rel span</span><br>
<span>Regular span</span><br>
<span>Regular span</span>
```